# How to display JSON data in DisplayActionSheet Xamarin?

Tags: json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to know how to fetch JSON data from a URL and display it in a DisplayActionSheet? I don't want to hardcode the data.

`JSON Data`

```
[
  {
    "id": 284,
    "name": "Complete Task"
  },
  {
    "id": 285,
    "name": "Uncomplete Task"
  },
  {
    "id": 286,
    "name": "Close Task"
  }
]
```

So far I have something like this, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right:

```
private const string TasksMenuUrl = "json-data-url-goes-here";
private ObservableCollection<TaskMenuOptions> _taskMenu;
private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

private async void FetchMenu()
{
     var menuContent = await _client.GetStringAsync(TasksMenuUrl);
     var taskMenu = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TaskMenuOptions>>(menuContent);

     _taskMenu = new ObservableCollection<TaskMenuOptions>(taskMenu);

     //var action = await DisplayActionSheet("Task Actions", "Cancel", null, "Complete Task", "Uncomplete Task", "Close Task");
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last argument in `DisplayActionSheet` is a `string[]`

```
var taskMenu = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TaskMenuOptions>>(menuContent);

var options = taskMenu.Select(t => t.Name).ToArray<string>();

var action = await DisplayActionSheet("Task Actions", "Cancel", null, options);
```